# Using a function to order an integer's digits from least to greatest?

Tags: sorting

Say you have an integer denoted as $n$. Is it possible to make a purely mathematical function that could take $n$ and order its digits from least to greatest?

I know how to do this programatically. I would simply break the integer up into a list composed of its digits, then iterate through that list with a for loop that compares the digits, and so on and so forth.

However, how could I do this without any data structures, manipulating $n$ only mathematically?

EDIT:

When I say manipulating $n$ only mathematically, I mean with arithmetic only. No breaking it up into a list or anything similar.

Comment: The function you describe is perfectly mathematical. Probably what you mean is if one can write such a function as a composition of "elementary" function (where elementary functions are the ones you see on a pocket calculator). In this sense the answer is probably not.

Comment: Well I have to create a data structure and manipulate each individual digit the way I stated in the OP. I'm trying to only manipulate the n using arithmetic. I don't mind flooring or comparing values with < or >.

Comment: The *datastructure* you need is *string*. In python: int(''.join(sorted(str(n))))

Comment: You misunderstand. I'm trying to do this without converting n from an integer (and henceforth without data structures).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$
f(n) = \min\left\{\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} a_{\sigma(k)} 10^k\colon \sigma\in\Sigma_n,\ \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} a_k 10^k = n,\ a_k\in\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}\right\}
$$
where $\Sigma_n$ is the set of permutations of $\{0,1,\dots,n-1\}$.

Comment: But this function returns a number, not an ordering. This function should return a permutation $\sigma$ that achieves the minimum, but it cannot do so without knowing the maximum number of digits a priori. Since $f$ should take as input any integer, this might not work.

Comment: (though I should say this answer is elegant and my concerns can easily be fixed; +1)

Comment: The OP says: "...takes $n$ and orders its digits...". I assume the result is the number with digits reordered.

Comment: That makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need several levels of logarithms and floor functions.

EDIT: Let's say we start with 121.

$log 121 ≈ 2.0828$

$\lfloor{log 121}\rfloor = 2$

$10^{\lfloor{log 121}\rfloor} = 100$

$\frac{121}{10^{\lfloor{log 121}\rfloor}} = 1.21$

$\lfloor \frac{121}{10^{\lfloor{log 121}\rfloor}} \rfloor = 1$ as the first digit

$121-1*10^{\lfloor{log 121}\rfloor} = 21$

$log21 ≈ 1.3222$

...

$\lfloor \frac{21}{10^{\lfloor{log 21}\rfloor}} \rfloor = 2$ as the second digit

$121-1*10^{\lfloor{log 121}\rfloor} - 2*10^{\lfloor{log 121-1*10^{\lfloor{log 121}\rfloor}}\rfloor} = 1$

...

$\lfloor \frac{1}{10^{\lfloor{log 1}\rfloor}} \rfloor = 1$ as the third digit

We now have the digits 1;1; and 2.

Comment: This doesn't explain how you would do it with logarithms and floor functions.

Comment: Yeah I kind of assumed this. I had something that my friend (who has already done this) said was 'kind of close' that multiplied the number by 10^x and then floored them to the value of 10^x-1 where x was 0 --> (num of digits in n) - 1

Comment: Now that I've actually written all of the way to this point, I just realized that the method I know for ordering numbers only works when there are only two of them, so it turns out that the person who down-voted this was right, this isn't actually as complete as I'd thought it would be. Oops